# Bazel on CentOS for Tensorflow with CUDA

Tags: centos, tensorflow, bazel

We had to use Bazel on CentOS 6 (no choice) in order to install TensorFlow, and it worked.

Unfortunately, we were not able to install TensorFlow with CUDA, thus so far it runs only on CPUs.

We think that it is because the link to the CUDA compiler is wrong.
How can we modify/tune Bazel in order to give the proper link?

Comment: You should be able to run TensorFlow's ./configure script and specify the path to the CUDA compiler, if not, what error are you getting?

Comment: The issue was that Centos 6 lacks of most of the common libraries. So we had to install them from source, and it was a nightmare so we gave up. We are waiting for the cluster administrators to accept to upgrade.

Comment: Have you tried this [reference](https://gist.github.com/gentaiscool/a628fab5cd98953af7f46b69463394b3).

Comment: @SG_Bazel Thank you but no. This question was asked 6 years ago, and your reference is 3 years old and applies to CentOS 7. In fact we gave up and switched all our work to PyTorch.

Comment: I see the above ask was from Centos so shared it. Thanks for the update